# send data in chunk mechanism architecture for multiple peers ios

Tags: ios, iphone, architecture, nsdata, multipeer-connectivity

i am working on multi-peer connectivity framework. I am using following code to send and received data in chunk.The code works in case of two devices. How ever for more than two devices it crash with **[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive (0x62, 0x70, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x73, 0x74, 0x30, 0x30)'**.

I know the reason why the crash happens, its because call

```
[self.mySession sendData:chunkData toPeers:[self.mySession connectedPeers] withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable error:nil]
```

at any point from with in MCSession Delegate didReceiveData delegate.
Can some one help me how should i architect my code to send data to multipeer connectivity.
I dont want to send complete data at once, and i know there will be no problem of crash in sending data and receiveing data all at once.
I want to send data in chunks, to all peers.The code i have tried for now:

```
-(void)sendData
{
[marrFileData removeAllObjects];

NSData *sendData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"test2.PNG"]);
NSUInteger length = [sendData length];
NSUInteger chunkSize = 100 * 1024;
NSUInteger offset = 0;
do {
    NSUInteger thisChunkSize = length - offset > chunkSize ? chunkSize : length - offset;
    NSData* chunk = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:(char *)[sendData bytes] + offset
                                         length:thisChunkSize
                                   freeWhenDone:NO];
    NSLog(@"chunk length : %lu",(unsigned long)chunk.length);

    [marrFileData addObject:[NSData dataWithData:chunk]];
    offset += thisChunkSize;
} while (offset < length);

noOfDataSend = 0;

if ([marrFileData count] > 0) {
    NSDictionary *dicContainer = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[marrFileData objectAtIndex:noOfDataSend], @"kChunkData", nil];
    NSData *chunkData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dicContainer];
    [self.mySession sendData:chunkData toPeers:[self.mySession connectedPeers] withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable error:nil];
}
}
```

**and receiver end is :**

```
- (void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
{
NSDictionary *dicContainer = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
NSData *chunkData = [dicContainer objectForKey:@"kChunkData"];
NSLog(@"data receiveddddd : %lu",(unsigned long)chunkData.length);

if (chunkData.length > 0) {
    if (chunkData.length < 2) {
        noOfDataSend++;
        NSLog(@"noofdatasend : %d",noOfDataSend);
        NSLog(@"array count : %d",marrFileData.count);
        if (noOfDataSend < ([marrFileData count])) {
            NSDictionary *dicContainer = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[marrFileData objectAtIndex:noOfDataSend], @"kChunkData", nil];
            NSData *chunkData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dicContainer];
            [self.mySession sendData:chunkData toPeers:[self.mySession connectedPeers] withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable error:nil];
        }else {
            NSDictionary *dicContainer = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[@"File Transfer Done" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], @"kChunkData", nil];
            NSData *chunkData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dicContainer];
            [self.mySession sendData:chunkData toPeers:[self.mySession connectedPeers] withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable error:nil];
        }
    } else {
        if ([[[NSString alloc] initWithData:chunkData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] isEqualToString:@"File Transfer Done"]) {
            [self appendFileData];
        }else {
            NSDictionary *dicContainer = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[@"1" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], @"kChunkData", nil];
            NSData *chunkData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dicContainer];
            [self.mySession sendData:chunkData toPeers:[self.mySession connectedPeers] withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable error:nil];
            [marrReceiveData addObject:chunkData];
        }
    }
}
```

}

Note: i tried using `[self.session sendData:chunkData toPeers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:peerID] withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable error:nil];` instead of `[self.session sendData:chunkData toPeers:[self.session connectedPeers] withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable error:nil];` in `- (void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID`, but data is not send to other devices.That is data initiated from device A receives on B or C but not on both B & C.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just send the `sendData` object? What's the point of all the chunking work?

Comment: Thanks Crish, you are right 99.9 % sample code i have seen on google with sendData all without chunk. 1.The data size, its dynamic and can be large.(share your exp on how much you are able i am testing for benchmarks ) 2.I need atleast one handshake from one device to another device, that is Device A will sned image id to B, and b will check in its db , and confirm to A either to send or not send.Then A will send actual image data.(here if i dont choose chunking still i have to adopt above way of communication and it will crash). Or if you can suggest me to achieve point 2.

Comment: So is your question basically asking what is the best method for transferring large amounts of data with MPC?

Comment: Any news on this topic? Have the same problem! Sending data (also big data) between two devices is no problem. But if i add one more i get the error like you! I